# Geolocation api with direction arrow

Tags: javascript, php, html, geolocation

I am building a simple PHP based off-road navigation webpage for use on a smartphone that will display two icons on a Google map, one being my my current location and one my destination. As I move, the position of the icon for me will automatically update.

Sample code to do the basic stuff includes:[This Stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505343/html5-geolocation-clearwatch-is-not-responding) and [This tutorial.](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)

I would like my icon to be an arrow that points in the direction I am currently walking. The direction would be based on my previous position and my current position. Does anyone know of any method to achieve that please?

One crude method would be to have 8 (or 16) icons, representing N, S, E, W, NE... and pick the icon that approximately matches my direction, but I was hoping for something more dynamic.

The other option is to simply draw a path on the map of where I have been. I am thinking of doing that anyway, but would also like the arrow.

To clarify exactly what I want, [This Stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505343/html5-geolocation-clearwatch-is-not-responding) contains this code to display a marker of my current position on a map:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
zoom: 18,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(startPos.coords.latitude, startPos.coords.longitude),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(startPos.coords.latitude, startPos.coords.longitude),
map: map
});
```

Instead of the teardrop type marker I want an arrow that is pointing in the direction I am walking. I would calculate the direction for it to point based on the lat/long of my previous location and my current location, but I need the code to insert in the above code where it says position:...

This is basic navigation stuff so I am sure it has been done before. I just haven't been able to find any examples. (I do not want to use Google directions API. It has a usage limit and is not really suited to off-road.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but it seems the Google Maps Javascript API provides functionality for this. You can use the [google.Maps.Symbol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol) object.

With the *rotation* property you can set the rotation of the symbol in degrees. You need to get the angle between the current location and destination from the API first then.

With the *path* property you can set a the symbol. Google already implemented symbols for arrows, they use the constants `BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW`, `BACKWARD_OPEN_ARROW`, `FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW` and `FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW`.

It also seems to support coloring, scaling, etc. for the symbol, so you can do quite some things with it. I hope this information helped.